# How to get alt attr from converted object into element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get alt of div's child but console logs $this.find is not a function.

```js
 const $ClickedCells = $(".board__cell--black");
  function pawnMove() {
    const $this = $(this)[0];
    const $thisPawn = $this.find("img");
    console.log($thisPawn);
  }
  $ClickedCells.on("click", pawnMove);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="board__cell--black"><img src="#" alt="lorem"></div>
<div class="board__cell--black"><img src="#" alt="lorem1"></div>
<div class="board__cell--black"><img src="#" alt="lorem2"></div>
<div class="board__cell--black"><img src="#" alt="lorem3"></div>
<div class="board__cell--black"><img src="#" alt="lorem4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:
When you do `$this = $(this)[0];`, you get HTML element on which find is not defined. You need to call find() on `$(this)`. `$(this)` represents jQuery element on which `find()` is available.

```
const $ClickedCells = $(".board__cell--black");
function pawnMove() {
   //const $this = $(this)[0];//<---Comment out this line
   const $thisPawn = $(this).find("img");
   onsole.log($thisPawn[0].alt);
}
$ClickedCells.on("click", pawnMove);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you are taking the HTML element, which has not the find method, that is a jQuery method:

```
const $this = $(this)[0]; // returns the HTML element
```

Change that line to:

```
const $this = $(this);
```

And your error will disappear.